# How to set "Content-type" header in RestEasy Client framework using a proxy interface?

Tags: json, api, rest, proxy, resteasy

I am using Resteasy client proxy framework to talk to a REST API. I have defined some methods on the proxy interface but unfortunately, I have some issues related to **Content-Type** not being set properly when sending http requests, which gives me an **http 400 (Bad Request) error code** since the remote API is expecting the **Content-type** header param to be **application/json**.

Here is how it looks like :

```
@Path("/")
public interface RestAPIClient {

  @POST
  @Path("/send")
  String send(@CookieParam("token") String token, @FormParam("name") String id, @FormParam("message") String message, @FormParam("emails") List<String> emails);

}
```

is there a way to set the "Content-type" header as "application/json" directly at the proxy interface level ? using some annotations maybe ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I you try a

```
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
```

on the POST ?

Take care of many things : you need to have an "entity" object who is send in the method (not @CookieParam, or @FormParam).
And in

So your method must be like :

```
@POST
@Path("/auth")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
ConnectionInformation auth(@CookieParam("name") String name, @CookieParam("password") String password, MyJSONObject entity);
```

and "entity" will produce the

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

you need.

Comment: I think I did but it didn't work either. I have specified the plain string "application/json" not MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON so maybe I should try this one. Let's see!

Comment: Nope not working and MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON is just an alias for "application/json"

Comment: Edited with advices :)

Answer (score 0):

As well as using:

```
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
```

you need to ensure there is actually content in the body of the request (not just params).

If there is no content, then the Content-Type header won't be set.